# How to return the single in a dataframe cell while maintaining datatype

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

So I have a dataframe that basically contains a dictionary in each cell. My index values are list of tuples like this [(10,0),(10,),(30,0),(25,2)] and the columns are just numbered starting at 1 and increasing from there.

I want to try and look up an index value and column number and have it return just the dictionary stored in that cell but maintain the dictionary data type. I've tried:

```
df.loc[[(10,0),(10,),(30,0),(25,2)],[1]].iloc[0]
```

But it looks like thats just returning a series and i'm just getting the first item in the series.

Edit:

### Edit

I was trying to keep it as simple as possible but I realize that might've been more convoluted.

I have two datadrames. 1 contains values and 2 contains a dictionary of results. I'm want to take the highest value from each column in df 1 and return the corresponding dictionary located at the same index value in df2.

so for example: column 1's highest value is .3818 located at ix val:
[(10,), (3,), (0,), (0, 10)]
So id like to return just the dictionary stored in column 1 at that index value in df2 so just: 
{'Total Net Profit': 1449.99999999996, 'Max Dr..}

here is what df1 and df2 look like:

```
                                     1         2    ...            4         5
[(10,), (2,), (0,), (0, 10)] -0.712821 -0.716000    ...    -0.392000 -0.952703
[(10,), (3,), (0,), (0, 10)]  0.381818  0.209091    ...     1.427273  0.115578
[(15,), (2,), (0,), (0, 10)] -0.929577 -0.527426    ...     0.033755 -0.219409
[(15,), (3,), (0,), (0, 10)] -1.000000 -0.768392    ...    -0.316076 -0.662125
[(20,), (2,), (0,), (0, 10)] -0.863118 -0.535948    ...    -0.513072 -0.735294


                                                                              1                        ...                                                                          5
[(10,), (2,), (0,), (0, 10)]  {'Total Net Profit': -750.0000000001708, 'Max ...                        ...                          {'Total Net Profit': -9900.00000000016, 'Max D...
[(10,), (3,), (0,), (0, 10)]  {'Total Net Profit': 1449.99999999996, 'Max Dr...                        ...                          {'Total Net Profit': -7400.000000000018, 'Max ...
[(15,), (2,), (0,), (0, 10)]  {'Total Net Profit': 200.00000000003115, 'Max ...                        ...                          {'Total Net Profit': -3800.0000000000255, 'Max...
[(15,), (3,), (0,), (0, 10)]  {'Total Net Profit': -1400.0000000000769, 'Max...                        ...                          {'Total Net Profit': -7150.000000000035, 'Max ...
[(20,), (2,), (0,), (0, 10)]  {'Total Net Profit': -400.0000000001336, 'Max ...                        ...                          {'Total Net Profit': -3500.0000000000146, 'Max...
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, it is hard to follow from your description

Comment: try `print(df.head())` and paste output here

Comment: made the edits and included the output @yuca

Answer (score 0):

you need `pd.DataFrame.idxmax`, try:

```
df2.loc[df1['1'].idmax(),1]
```